# returning javascript object alerting "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I apologize ahead of time because I feel like this is such a simple question, but I'm new so I don't quite understand how to do it yet!

I'm geocoding an address and I return the coordinates:

```
//Geocoder
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

//Submit listener and alert the coordinates
submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(geocodeAddress(geocoder, map)));
});

//Geocodes an address and returns the lat lng
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    geocoder.geocode({address: address.value}, function(addressLatLng, status) {

        //Checks if status returned was ok
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            //adds pin to map and centers map on pin
            resultsMap.setCenter(addressLatLng[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                position: addressLatLng[0].geometry.location
            });
            //alert(addressLatLng[0].geometry.location);
            return(addressLatLng[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
            alert('No address was found, please try again!');
        }
    });
}
```

If I alert them inside the function, it alerts them correctly (i.e. {20.12345, 20.12345}. If I alert them on the submit button, it just says "undefined." How would I correctly return those coordinates? (I ultimately have to do something with them, not just alert them) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
//Geocoder
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

//Submit listener and alert the coordinates
submit.addEventListener('click', function() { //This is callback
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, function(loc){
      alert(loc || 'No address was found, please try again!');   
    });
});

//Geocodes an address and returns the lat lng
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, cb) {
    geocoder.geocode({address: address.value}, function(addressLatLng, status) {

        //Checks if status returned was ok
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            //adds pin to map and centers map on pin
            resultsMap.setCenter(addressLatLng[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                position: addressLatLng[0].geometry.location
            });
             //call cb with location details
            cb(addressLatLng[0].geometry.location);
        } else {
            //call the callback with empty value
            cb('');
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works! after looking at what you did and the comment @millerbr had, it makes sense now why it was returning undefined.

Comment: Thanks! :) I have one more question! The data displayed comes back as (12.345, 12.345) with the lat first and the long second. How would I alert just one or the other?

Comment: Something on the lines of `var Parsedloc = '(12.345,59.123)'.replace('(','').replace(')','').split(',');`

Comment: `parsedloc[0]` first value in string and `parsedloc[1]` the second one. These values are in string you might wanna do `parseFloat`...

Comment: Replace can be done with regex as well. But as I'm on the move... I can't test what I am writing... Hope this is what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an async problem. You need to return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from your function, and then call the alert when the promise is fulfilled.

The reason alert is showing undefined is because the function hasn't finished yet, so it hasn't returned by the time the alert is shown.